# How can I get my data from my buffer into this struct?

Tags: c

I am trying to copy data from a buffer that contains characters into a struct. The buffer only contains data for the blue, green, and red members of the struct - alpha will be set to zero. The code is as follows, but I can't seem to get the loops figured out.

```
   typedef struct __attribute__((packed)){
      uint8_t blue;
      uint8_t green;
      uint8_t red;
      uint8_t alpha;
   } rgb_pixel_t;

    int i, j;
    char *buffer; 
    buffer = malloc(sizeof(rgb_pixel_t) * bmp->dib.width); 

    bmp_malloc_pixels(bmp);
    rgb_pixel_t pixel = {42, 42, 42, 0}; 

    fseek(fp, bmp->header.offset, SEEK_SET);
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), ((bmp->dib.depth / 8) * bmp->dib.width), fp);

    for(i = 0; i < 600; ++i) {
            for(j = 0; j < 400; ++j) {
                    bmp_set_pixel(bmp, i, j, pixel); // This isn't right.
            }   
    }
```

Comment: If you are sure that fread is reading the values as it should, the loop is perfectly okay. If I am not wrong, this is using libbmp, no?

Comment: I don't see how you're accessing the buffer in the first place...

Comment: Yes, I am using libbmp.

Comment: The line with the comment would be the place to set copy into the struct I think...

Comment: I don't think there are many (if any) compilers where the presence of the `__attribute__((packed))` makes any difference whatsoever.

Comment: Where do the 600 and 400 come from?  Why aren't they based on parts of `bmp`, maybe even `bmp->dib.depth` and `bmp->dib.width`?

Comment: Jonathan: __attribute__((packed)) absolutely makes a difference using gcc 4.2 under Darwin. It prevents the structs from having padding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it that way. Instead of having a `char` buffer, have a `rgb_pixel_t` buffer, and read into that:

```
rgb_pixel_t *pixels = malloc(sizeof(rgb_pixel_t) * bmp->dib.width);

/* ... */

size_t pixels_to_read = bmp->dib.depth / 8 * bmp->dib.width / sizeof(rgb_pixel_t);
fread(pixels, sizeof(rgb_pixel_t), pixels_to_read, fp);

/* ... */
```

---

As noted by [Drew McGowen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2478565/drew-mcgowen) in a comment, this will of course not work if the bitmap data doesn't have an alpha channel. Also, there are images that have less bits per pixel, or that doesn't have RGB data at all (instead have index into color table, typically images with 256 colors or less).

You might want to find a library which handle all that for you, and present format-independent API for you to use, instead of having to muck around with the raw image data yourself.

Comment: Be careful - if the image is a packed 24 bits per pixel, and you try to read 32 bits per pixel, your solution won't work.

Comment: How could I account for that?

Comment: You'll need to make a loop for each pixel and manually copy each byte.